# TYPO3 11 LTS Generation of Frontend Url in REST API Context

Tags: typo3, url-routing, extbase, typo3-11.x

Hi I need some support regarding frontend url generation inside building REST API. I'm using restler for the API.
I could generate the url with

```
$site = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(SiteFinder::class)->getSiteByPageId($arguments['pageUid']);
return (string)$site->getRouter()->generateUri($arguments['pageUid'],$queryStrings);
```

But the problem is it is not building the extension parameters using the routing configuration. The url works as expected.

Update:
To get more understanding: I added the info more.
This is same like generating a frontend url in backend, scheduler task or command controller. Where GLOBALS['TSFE'] not available.

I use the above function like this.

```
public function generateUrl(
    int $pageId,
    array $arguments,
    bool $absolute
): string
{
    $site = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(SiteFinder::class)->getSiteByPageId($pageId);
    if (empty($site->getBase()->getHost()) || empty($site->getBase()->getScheme())) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(
            "Site " . $site->getIdentifier() . ' does not have proper schema or host set. Thus not usable in cli context.',
            1648736865
        );
    }
    $uri = $site
        ->getRouter()
        ->generateUri(
            $pageId,
            $arguments,
            '',
            PageRouter::ABSOLUTE_URL
        );
    if (empty($uri->getHost()) || empty($uri->getScheme())) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(
            'Build uri did not have proper schema or host set. Thus not usable in cli context. ' . (string)$uri,
            1648736938
        );
    }
    if (!$absolute) {
        return $uri->getPath() . (!empty($uri->getQuery()) ? '?' . $uri->getQuery() : '');
    }
    return (string)$uri;
}
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: Please add more details, especially how `$queryStrings` looks like. Normally this should be an array so `$parameters` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

if you have PageUid already and Arguments then you can try building URI with UriBuilder of TYPO3.

```
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\Routing\UriBuilder
```

```
$uriBuilder = $renderingContext->getControllerContext()->getUriBuilder();
$uriBuilder->reset();

if ($pageUid > 0) {
    $uriBuilder->setTargetPageUid($pageUid);
}

if ($pageType > 0) {
    $uriBuilder->setTargetPageType($pageType);
}

if ($noCache === true) {
    $uriBuilder->setNoCache($noCache);
}

if (is_string($section)) {
    $uriBuilder->setSection($section);
}

if (is_string($format)) {
    $uriBuilder->setFormat($format);
}

if (is_array($additionalParams)) {
    $uriBuilder->setArguments($additionalParams);
}

if ($absolute === true) {
    $uriBuilder->setCreateAbsoluteUri($absolute);
}

if ($addQueryString === true) {
    $uriBuilder->setAddQueryString($addQueryString);
}

if (is_array($argumentsToBeExcludedFromQueryString)) {
    $uriBuilder->setArgumentsToBeExcludedFromQueryString($argumentsToBeExcludedFromQueryString);
}

if ($addQueryStringMethod !== '') {
    $uriBuilder->setAddQueryStringMethod($addQueryStringMethod);
}

if ($linkAccessRestrictedPages === true) {
    $uriBuilder->setLinkAccessRestrictedPages($linkAccessRestrictedPages);
}

return $uriBuilder->uriFor($action, $arguments, $controller, $extensionName, $pluginName);
```

Comment: This will throw an error in the API context. As I told this is not a general frontend. It's in my API layer. Same as a cronjob (scheduler task) or command controller.

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem.
The issue was with the arguments I supplied to the generate Url function.
I prepared the arguments like this:

```
array(3) {
  ["tx_vshcore_profilesdetail[action]"]=>
  string(6) "detail"
  ["tx_vshcore_profilesdetail[controller]"]=>
  string(8) "Profiles"
  ["tx_vshcore_profilesdetail[profile]"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

I think about the PHP function http_build_query and prepare my arguments like the above. But it should be like this.

```
array(1) {
  ["tx_vshcore_profilesdetail"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["controller"]=>
    string(8) "Profiles"
    ["action"]=>
    string(6) "detail"
    ["profile_detail"]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

I hope it is clear where I'm wrong :).